# Not able to prevent couchbase autoconfiguration during tests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase, spring-boot-test, spring-data-couchbase

I am trying to prevent the application from attempting to connect to the DB while running the Unit tests. Following is what I have done.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        CouchbaseDataAutoConfiguration.class,
        CouchbaseAutoConfiguration.class,
    })
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = {
        ApplicationStartup.class, MessageApplication.class }))
public class MessageApplicationTests {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MessageApplicationTests.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = MessageApplicationTests.class)
class TestClass {

    @Autowired
    Serviceclass serviceclass;


    @Test
    void testMethod() {

        
    }
}
```

Apart from this, I have added the following in application-test.yml

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.couchbase.CouchbaseDataAutoConfiguration
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.couchbase.CouchbaseAutoConfiguration
      - org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.messaging.MessagingAutoConfiguration
```

Both are not helping.
Can someone help me understand what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also exclude your Config class (the one that extends AbstractCouchbaseConfig)
But if you have any references to repositories such as via Autowire or as args to @Service constructors, the application will fail to start.  The exclude of auto configuration classes did not seem to matter when I tried it.

@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = {
ApplicationStartup.class, MessageApplication.class, Config.class}))

---

Probably not related to your issue, but I found that with multiple @SpringBootApplication classes (you have MessageApplication and MessageApplicationTests, right?), that Spring goes through the auto-config classes for *both* of them, not just the one in
SpringApplication.run(MessageApplicationTests.class, args) ) So one would  need @SpringBootApplication excludes on both classes to completely exclude them (although I found that excluding didn't change anything).

Answer (score 2):

The above answer posted by Michael Reiche is correct. Adding few more points to address the concern raised by him.

We need to exclude the configuration class for Couchbase. But the autowired repository beans would create a problem then.

To resolve it we can mock the repository beans so that it doesn't try to create actual repository beans and load them to the context.

Not including the autoconfiguration classes in the exclusion list did matter for me, as it would try to configure the Couchbase since the dependency is there in the classpath

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { 
        CouchbaseDataAutoConfiguration.class, CouchbaseAutoConfiguration.class,
        CouchbaseRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class, CouchbaseReactiveDataAutoConfiguration.class,
        CouchbaseReactiveHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class

})
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value = {
        ApplicationStartup.class, MessageApplication.class , CouchBaseConfiguration.class }))
public class MessageApplicationTests {

    @MockBean
    Repositoryclass repoBean;
```

Answer (score 2):

The spring-data-couchbase project tests provide a mock couchbase server (src/test/resources/integration.properties -> mocked) or can use a standalone couchbase server (unmanaged). That might be useful for your testing.